# Memory consumed by object in java

Tags: java, object, memory, memory-management

I have an object which contains some data. How to know the memory occupied by the object in bytes in java?

```
SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
obj.initialize(Data);
```

Here I have sample object 'obj' of SomeClass

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to get indivisible object's memory. but using Runtime Class jvm memory size you can check.